# Computing wt. avegrage in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data like this

```
++--------------------
|Item|TAT | Percentage|
-----------------------
|  1| 2  |    10%     |
|  2| 3  |    90%     |
----------------------
```

My formula to get the above output like this :
`(TAT * Percentage) + (tat * percentage)` or `(2*10%) + (3*90%)` then Result for this is`2.9`

Can you please help me to do this in sql?  I Don't know how to convert whole number to percent in sql.
TIA!

Comment: What's the datatype of `Percentage` in your database?

Comment: And only two rows?

Comment: I just get the percentage column by getting the avg(TAT)

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUM` aggregate

```
SELECT Sum(TAT * Percentage / 100.0)
FROM   (VALUES (1,2,10),
               (2,3,90)) tc (item, tat, Percentage)
```

**Result :** `2.900000`

To find `n` percentage of `x` amount this is the formula

> x * (n/100)

Comment: This is what im asking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
     select AVG( cast(TAT as int )*cast(LEFT(Percentage,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Percentage)-1) as int)) 
    from #TableName
```

Comment: Whats this? And what is the result for the above script?

Answer (score -1):

```
select sum(l.a) from (select t.TAT*t.Percentage as a from table t ) l ;
```

you can add the where to filter the result before sum.

Comment: change the sum to avg,it's the result.